# Infinite square root muliplication $(x=3\sqrt{y\sqrt{3\sqrt{y}....}})$

Tags: square-numbers

I have this problem which says
$$
x=3\sqrt{y\sqrt{3\sqrt{y\cdots}}}\\
y=3\sqrt{x\sqrt{3\sqrt{x\cdots}}}
$$
What is $x+y$
I tried 
$$
x^2=9y\sqrt{x}\\
x^3=81y^2\\
y^3=81x^2\\
x^3+y^3=81(x^2+y^2)\\
(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=81(x^2+y^2)
$$
I don't know what to do or if I am do that right

Comment: Use proper Latex codification otherwise this post will be closed. It is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: sorry, I've edited it

Comment: Much better, thanks!

Comment: I changed the second line to $y = {}$, since that makes more sense with what comes after, and it was in the original version of the question,

Answer (score 1):

From second equality we obtain
$$x^2=9x\sqrt{x},$$ which gives $x=0$ or $x=81$. The rest is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x \neq 0 \neq y$. From $x^3=81y^2$ and $y^3=81x^2$, it follows that $\frac{x^3}{y^3}=\frac{y^2}{x^2}$, hence $x^5=y^5$, so $x=y$. I think you can take it from there.

Comment: oh,I appreciate that

Comment: OK! If you think this is the right answer, please tick it as such!